# JS || Обращение к элементу коллекции

Tags: javascript, node.js, коллекции

У меня есть следующая коллекция:

```js
Collection [Map] {
  '339295220585725952' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '339295220585725952',
       username: 'LiteEN✔',
       discriminator: '6114',
       avatar: 'c2b0f63d3f5124adeb64a115daaeedb2',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548595143452,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: false,
    selfDeaf: false,
    voiceSessionID: '53b2784cd1738563c2218942c1079c31',
    voiceChannelID: '535913598766022678',
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Steven Hover',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '242705657835421698' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '242705657835421698',
       username: 'nosok02(gigabyte)',
       discriminator: '6061',
       avatar: 'd599e4e7941c1af3527c51d720c07a1b',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1547843784110,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: false,
    selfDeaf: false,
    voiceSessionID: '6b772c49b1ad8527918b77f5af149ee4',
    voiceChannelID: '535913598766022678',
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Jordan Piterson',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '210037338003210243' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '210037338003210243',
       username: '[R-LV] Colin_Rose [3]',
       discriminator: '7216',
       avatar: '0e1d1a69ea8b49a024247626ca55e2cf',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548786272205,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: false,
    selfDeaf: false,
    voiceSessionID: '828fb1cb5b3426d19a078f4d3622695e',
    voiceChannelID: '535913598766022678',
    speaking: false,
    nickname: null,
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '307914992152477706' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '307914992152477706',
       username: '[$FARMER$][Мин. Юст.]Gans_Miller',
       discriminator: '3598',
       avatar: '2d1311aa9e4f0694655d82103290296e',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548603461889,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Gans Miller',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '319392609460158464' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '319392609460158464',
       username: 'Fire_Ice',
       discriminator: '7090',
       avatar: '2bfa470a93178981d234300e769dc580',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548609766152,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Oleg Avramenko',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '320652579455631363' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '320652579455631363',
       username: '!Клайд',
       discriminator: '1316',
       avatar: 'baeadc5c1eca15c41d77fed7fc0cb2b1',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548610195271,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Clyde Capone',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '332805879378477056' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '332805879378477056',
       username: 'Шариз',
       discriminator: '5288',
       avatar: '14de64a4742b2a341d48a6d38991d23c',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548609863917,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Frank Village',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '379677386834182145' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '379677386834182145',
       username: '∆ √Drek_Barrosa √',
       discriminator: '0725',
       avatar: '2c8d7d4b133fe6ff0b8b571d1290e4ea',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548605781196,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Drek Barrosa',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '383306579245531139' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '383306579245531139',
       username: 'Андрей Дарт',
       discriminator: '7120',
       avatar: '82216f9a96c2d11423775620a97d7aab',
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548587971013,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Andrii Darth',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false },
  '434717173810724864' => GuildMember {
    guild:
     Guild {
       members: [Collection],
       channels: [Collection],
       roles: [Collection],
       presences: [Collection],
       deleted: false,
       available: true,
       id: '534791311434448897',
       name: '#Scottdale || Парламент',
       icon: '85ea87471a6a921ddb3f7f38c3a37b70',
       splash: null,
       region: 'eu-central',
       memberCount: 14,
       large: false,
       features: [],
       applicationID: null,
       afkTimeout: 300,
       afkChannelID: null,
       systemChannelID: '534791311434448901',
       embedEnabled: undefined,
       verificationLevel: 0,
       explicitContentFilter: 0,
       mfaLevel: 0,
       joinedTimestamp: 1547864050757,
       defaultMessageNotifications: 'ALL',
       ownerID: '347827337137750016',
       _rawVoiceStates: [Collection],
       emojis: Collection [Map] {} },
    user:
     User {
       id: '434717173810724864',
       username: '[KFC] Danil_Kartery [РМ] [VIPL]',
       discriminator: '9866',
       avatar: null,
       bot: false,
       lastMessageID: null,
       lastMessage: null },
    joinedTimestamp: 1548605906833,
    _roles: [ '535915484768501781' ],
    serverDeaf: false,
    serverMute: false,
    selfMute: undefined,
    selfDeaf: undefined,
    voiceSessionID: undefined,
    voiceChannelID: undefined,
    speaking: false,
    nickname: 'Danil Kartery',
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null,
    deleted: false } }
```

Я хочу получить все id пользователей. Они находятся в user: User{id: 'id'}. Как я могу к ним обратиться?

Comment: Что это за "коллекция" такая? В JS нет такого типа.

Comment: Это коллекция с Discord.js. let users = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Голосующие").members

Comment: Приведите её в JSON, выведете в консоль и приложите лог. `console.log(JSON.stringify(users));`

Comment: выводит пустой объект - {}

Comment: тоесть `console.log(users)` выводит Вашу коллекцию, а приведенная в JSON пустой массив?

Comment: Да, как-то странно выходит

Comment: Проверьте еще раз свой код, и в том месте где Вы смогли получить эту колекцию, выведите в лог ту же переменную но только в JSON. Возможно Вы изменяете её где то еще